# Label only specific features related to Atlas feature?

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas

I have a shapefile of about 100 streets and another one of all the districts within a city. Some of these streets run over multiple districts. In QGIS, I use the atlas tool to successively print maps of theses streets one by one.

[image: A street running over two districts]

How can I only display the labels for the districts under each individual street street in the atlas?

I tried doing this with rule based styling. I tried using the [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) pluging and other [spatial operators](https://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/11/06/Spatial-operators-in-QGIS-expression) in the field calculator.

Comment: You have tried rule labels: intersects ($ geometry, @atlas_geometry) = 1 to do on districts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule label and use the following formula
  'Intersects ($ geometry, @atlas_geometry) = 1' to do on districts

You must have created the atlas to use @atlas_geometry
[image]