# Prevent labeling outside of a an inverted styled polygon

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

I have this situation:

[image]

All layers are filtered to the region except the layer "bahnstrecken" who is missing that attribute. Instead I use the polygon "bundeslaender" (inverted polygon style) to overwrite features of the layer "bahnstrecken" (black lines) outside of the shown region. This works perfect. But as soon I want to label the "bahnstrecken" (which I did with orange numbers), the labels show up outside the region. I only want to show the labels WITHIN the region.

I know the problem can be solved by just clipping the "bahnstrecken"-layer to the region. But I am just curious: Is there any other way how I can solve the problem, without manipulating the data?

Comment: You may want to check the Mask plugin that claim to be able to do that...

Comment: Great, that works almost perfect. Just a few labels near the border (but still outside of the region) are shown. Big improvement. But is there any other solution without downloading a plugin?

Comment: You could try to use rule based labelling with an expression using "intersects" to filter outside labels (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326892/qgis-spatial-filtering-expressions for a somewhat related exemple of using intersects)

Comment: I love that! I used that expression for rulebased labeling and it works: intersects ( $geometry, geometry(get_feature('bundeslaender','name','Thüringen'))). But still, a few numbers near the border but outside the region-polygon appear. This is understandable because some line segments of "bahnstrecken" are both within and outside of the region polygon. I tried the same expression with WITHIN instead of INTERSECTS and it labels only the line features that are fully within the polygon. Great!

Comment: nice to see you make it work, you should put that as an answer so other people with the same problem will find it

Comment: And how would that expression look like when I only want to label points inside a polygon in an atlas? I don't want to label the points outside of the current atlas feature. The atlas is based on a polygon-layer.

Comment: more or less like this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245297/label-only-specific-features-related-to-atlas-feature

Comment: I tried that expression, but it didn't work. I opened a new thread, got an answer and that expression worked very well for me: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376629/how-do-i-prevent-labeling-outside-of-the-current-atlas-feature-polygon/376636#376636